# How to display output of a program in c on gtk window?

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I have a program coded in c. now i want to display its output on a gtk window.
Right now i am getting my output on console, i want this ouput to be fed to gtk+
so that i display it on a window. my output of program is a integer value.

I am new to gtk+.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`g_spawn_sync()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-sync) and friends.

Comment: can u provide me with a example? I am very new to this

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `g_spawn_command_line_sync` to display the results of a command in a `GtkTextView`: http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=906

This code example is old and uses Libglade (which has been replaced by GtkBuilder), but, the code in the `on_execute_button_clicked` function demonstrates what you're looking for.

Comment: can u provide me with a example?